# Prepend 0s to string (to specific length)

Tags: sql, string, loops, prepend, string-length

I have a query where I'm pulling in a check number from the database. The return value needs to always be 9 characters exactly. Most of the check numbers are only 6 characters, so I want to prepend 0s to to the string to ensure it is always exactly 9 characters. Since the check numbers can vary in length, it will be a different number of 0s for each one. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're always between 6 and 9 digits, the easiest (and probably best) way to go is using CASE.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(CHECK_NUM)= 6 THEN '000' WHEN LEN(CHECK_NUM) = 7 THEN '00' 
       WHEN 
       LEN(CHECK_NUM) = 8 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CHECK_NUM 
FROM   TABLE
```

**EDIT**
In case the original values are numbers (`int`), try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(CHECK_NUM)= 6 THEN '000' WHEN LEN(CHECK_NUM) = 7 THEN '00' 
       WHEN 
       LEN(CHECK_NUM) = 8 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + CAST(CHECK_NUM AS VARCHAR(9)) 
FROM   TABLE1
```

Take a look at the this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1611d/2).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried it, however, it doesn't appear to be actually adding the zeros to the beginning:

select case 
  when LEN(cr.CHECK_NUM_NUMERIC) = 6 
  then '000'
  when LEN(cr.CHECK_NUM_NUMERIC) = 7 
  then '00'
  when LEN(cr.CHECK_NUM_NUMERIC) = 8 
  then '0'
  else ''
  end + cr.CHECK_NUM_NUMERIC   
from chk_reconciliation cr

Comment: Is the field a int or a varchar?